# When is the n+l rule followed when working with energy of different orbitals?

Tags: orbitals, atoms, atomic-structure

While going through my book, I came across a problem which gave some options about the order of energy of **3s, 3p and 3d** orbitals of hydrogen atom. The correct answer was given as:

> **3s, 3p and 3d orbitals all have the same energy**

---

I also read somewhere that the order of energy of different orbitals increases as the value of $n+l$ increases where $n$ is the principal quantum number and $l$ is the azimuthal quantum number. So my guess was $3s<3p<3d$ .

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The former is true for hydrogen atom, the latter for other atoms.

Comment: `1s.                                                                                
 2s.   2p.                                                                            
 3s.   3p.   3d.                                                                            
 4s.   4p.   4d.    4f.                                                                                 
 5s.   5p.   5d.    5f.                                                             
 6s.   6p.   6d.                                                                                    
 7s.   7p.                     
 8s.`

Comment: moeller diagram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3s, 3p and 3d orbitals all have the same energy in hydrogen atoms ( or monoelectron atomic ions ) according to the nonrelativistic Schroedinger model.

Fine measurements and relativistic models of hydrogen atoms shows there is slight difference in their energies, related to the [fine structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure) of spectra  and Lamb shift ( [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift)  [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/lamb.html) )

For multielectron atoms, s, p, d orbitals have different energies, as there come in the play 2 major effects, which affect electron energies:

1. Mutual electron repulsion
2. Screening/shielding of the nucleus charge by other electrons.

Comment: oh so as the 2 effects don't take place in the case of mono electron species, we can say that they'll have the same energy. If for a moment we imagine a hypothetical case where these 2 effects don't exist at all, would the energy be same in multi electron species just like it was in the case of Hydrogen?

Comment: Yes, we can say they have the same energy as the first approximation.// Yes, they would have had approximately the same energy too, but what is the point of such highly hypothetical thought ?